# Filtering the elements of an array to split them into two categories

Tags: list-manipulation, syntax

So, I am new to *Mathematica*, and I am trying to write something that involves taking values from one array and separating them into two different arrays.  My code for doing this is:

```
For[i = 1, i < (TruncationOrder + 1), i++,
    (If[(Abs[Im[evalueb1[[1, i]]]] < 10^-14),
        (If[Re[evalueb1[[1, i]]] > 0,
            ρplus[[i, i]] = evalueb1[[1, i]],
            ρminus[[i, i]] = evalueb1[[1, i]]]),
         If[Im[evalueb1[[1, i]]] > 0,
            ρplus[[i, i]] = evalueb1[[1, i]],
            ρminus[[i, i]] = evalueb1[[1, i]]]])];
```

However, this does not give the desired results.  I randomly have '1' several times in my new array.  The actual values are given below:

Original:

```
 {-0.651301 - 2.44576*10^-16 I, 0.651301 + 3.73803*10^-17 I, 0.671298 - 6.68417*10^-16 I,
  -0.671305 + 1.17248*10^-17 I, -0.000107956 + 0.735512 I, -0.000107956 - 
  0.735512 I,
  9.93642*10^-6 + 0.764605 I, 9.93642*10^-6 - 0.764605 I, -0.965926 + 5.29506*10^-16 I,
  0.965926 + 3.76737*10^-16 I, 0.97048 + 4.33453*10^-16 I, -0.97048 + 5.39299*10^-16 I,
  0.0344992 - 1.4214 I, 0.0344992 + 1.4214 I, 0.0028631 + 1.4505 I, 0.0028631 - 1.4505 I,
  -0.0626803 + 1.78014 I, -0.0626803 - 1.78014 I, -0.12443 + 1.98252 I, -0.12443 - 1.98252 I,
  0.167724 - 2.24691 I, 0.167724 + 2.24691 I}
```

New incorrect ones:

`ρplus`:

```
    {1, 0.651301 + 3.73803*10^-17 I, 0.671298 - 6.68417*10^-16 I, 1, -0.000107956 + 0.735512 I,
     1, 9.93642*10^-6 + 0.764605 I, 1, 1, 0.965926 + 3.76737*10^-16 I,
     0.97048 + 4.33453*10^-16 I}
```

`ρminus`:

```
    {-0.651301 - 2.44576*10^-16 I, 1, 1, -0.671305 + 1.17248*10^-17 I,
     1, -0.000107956 - 0.735512 I, 1, 9.93642*10^-6 - 0.764605 I,
     -0.965926 + 5.29506*10^-16 I, 1, 1}
```

Comment: What is "original"? `evalueb1`?

Comment: since pplus pminus evalub1 are 2d arrays, what you are showing for original and incorrect isn't any of them

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you pre-initialized your `ρplus` and `ρminus` lists with a vector of ones, which is why you see them in the result at positions where the conditions don't satisfy. Presumably, you come from a MATLAB/procedural programming background, and I suggest you read [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18396/5) (and all other answers on that question) and [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7924/5) and familiarize yourself with the different list manipulation and iterating functions before proceeding.

As for your problem, you can write it neatly in a *Mathematica* style using `Select` as:

```
With[{TruncationOrder = 5, absTest = Abs@Im@# < 10^(-14) &, reTest = Re@# > 0 &, imTest = Im@# > 0 &},

    pplus = Select[evalueb1[[;; TruncationOrder]], 
        (absTest@# && reTest@#) || (Not@absTest@# && imTest@#) &];

    pminus = Select[evalueb1[[;; TruncationOrder]],
        (absTest@# && Not@reTest@#) || (Not@absTest@# && Not@imTest@#) &];
]
```

Comment: Sorry if this is a dumb question, but what do the @ sign and the # sign mean?

Comment: It means you should have a look at the fine manual! And [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users) as well...! ;)

Comment: @cormullion Searching for [`@`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Prefix.html) returns a single reference which has to do with output formatting, and it is not immediately clear that `f@x` is equivalent to `f[x]`. Some interpretation is required to achieve that.

Comment: @rcollyer True enough (and where's Misery to complain about the documentation when we need him...?). But I know that some basic familiarity with Mathematica syntax is usually expected here, so I thought I'd hint as much...

Comment: @cormullion on some level expecting some familiarity with the syntax is expected. However, we _all_ had to learn it somewhere, and it took me longer than I care to admit to find this [tutorial on shorthand notations](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/howto/UseShorthandNotations.html). Of course, it seems to contain a number of things, so it is a good link, in general.